# 404 Not found - why can't I open any views in laravel except for "/"?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, ubuntu

my virtual host is:

```
 brk.localhost
```

directed to my laravel application public folder.

my routes.php

```
Route::get('/login', function(){
return view('login');
 });
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

and I have a file named login.blade.php in my views directory

but when i'm going to "http://brk.localhost/" works perfectly getting the home page but when I try to go to "http://brk.localhost/login" I get the "404 Not Found message."

need help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable mod_rewrite:

`sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Comment: well this is odd, but trying to go to http://brk.localhost/index.php/login works, what is that?

Comment: It sounds like mod_rewrite isn't enabled.

Comment: oh, finally, please write a solution with the mod_rewrite so I can vote, thanks alot

Comment: Oh, great. Glad we finally solved it! I have just edited my answer.